# Android Studio custom template

Tags: android, templates, android-studio

I made a template to save time for my structured projects.

It's a base template so I only use it when I create a new project, but Android Studio shows my template also when I want to create a new object (Xml, class, activity, fragment, etc).

I want to only show my template as an option when I want to create a new project. I tried to find something to change it, but I didn't get anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to `<android studio directory>\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities` and look to templates defined there.

I done same thing. I didn't found how to create a template for new project, so i have just created a template for new module.

Raccomended reading are:

- http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/resources-and-tools/6845-android-adt-template-format-document.html
- http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/215-mobile/6843-custom-projects-in-android-studio.html
- http://robusttechhouse.com/tutorial-how-to-create-custom-android-code-templates/
- https://coderwall.com/p/fsxvyw/file-templates-in-android-studio

Comment: Have you tried to create dynamic custom template?
I wanna make one template which has fields internally dependent. how can i make one?

Comment: Maybe, after all these years, you still have a code for a module's template? Although i think now it is irrelevant. Anyway, i have not found ANY examples of custom android modules template, so that would be very useful.

Comment: Yes I still have the code. If you find it useful I can share it on github. Just give me a week (I'm in holiday :)).

Comment: The templates folder under lib/ doesn't exist anymore, do you know if it has moved somewhere else ?