# where can I find "Phone & Tablet Module" and "Android Library" 's template code?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I want to modify Android Studio's default Module template：
[image: Android Studio New Module]

and I can find most of the template code at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects [windows]

[image]

but I cannot find anything about "Phone & Tablet Module" and "Android Library"

My Android Studio version is 3.0.1

Comment: **File->New->New Module** you can find lib and phone tablet module.

Comment: @HemantParmar I need its template code, beacuse I want to modify it

Comment: sorry i am not getting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396299/android-studio-custom-template?rq=1 @HemantParmar